# How to stop mousewheel in Windows File Explorer from doing strange things?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, mouse-wheel

I have been using the Windows File Explorer as one does, using the mouse wheel to scroll up and down the list of files in a directory.

But sometimes this stops working; instead of scrolling up and down the list, the mouse wheel starts selecting from all the different options on the View tab. Once it starts doing this the only way I have found to restore normal service is to reboot the machine.

So, does anyone know what makes it decide to do this (so I can avoid it), or how to get normal behaviour back again (other than by restarting)?

Comment: Your mouse might be the problem here. Can you try another one and see if the problem still occurs?

Comment: @Alex, not readily; if I can I will and will add what happens to the question.

Comment: Is there any hardware/cable/connection problem? Is that happens for all folders?